# Razor syntax inside attributes of html elements (ASP MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table with repeating customer rows, I would like to add the customer ID to the ID attribute of my table rows like this:

```
<tr id="row<customer id>"></tr>
```

I try adding this code:

```
@foreach(var c in Model) {
   <tr id="row@c.id"></tr>
}
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
<tr id="row@c.id"></tr>
<tr id="row@c.id"></tr>
```

etc.

But I would like it to be:

```
<tr id="row1"></tr>
<tr id="row2"></tr>
```

etc.

I also tried to add `<tr>row@{c.id}</tr>` but it did not work..

Answer (score 120, accepted):

have you tried `<tr>row@(c.id)</tr>`?

The actual reason why this doesn't work is because your `row@c.id` matches the *regex* for an email address. So the parser assumes it's an email and not actually an attempt to call code. The reason `row@{c.id}` doesn't work is because the `@{}` doesn't output and is meant to contain blocks of code.

When in doubt you should use `@()` as it will force what's contained between the `()` to be parsed as code.

Comment: Thank you, I dont have the highlighter, so it is not easy for me to see. Have to install that one ASAP :P