# Razor print variable near HTML number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a really noob question for you today. Please keep in mind that this is my first project in Razor so don't be too harsh :)

The problem happens when I print variables to a template. 
When it's a simple string I have no problem, but when it's a number it just doesn't print the value.

Works

```
string url = @CurrentPage.Site.Replace("http://", "").Replace("https://", "");
<a href="//@url" target="_blank">@url</a>
// prints - <a href="//www.google.pt" target="_blank">www.google.pt</a>
```

Doesn't work

```
string num = @CurrentPage.Telefone.Replace(" ", "");
<a href="tel:+123@num">@CurrentPage.Telefone</a>
// prints - <a href="tel:+123@num">123 456 789</a>
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Razor syntax inside attributes of html elements (ASP MVC 3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696071/razor-syntax-inside-attributes-of-html-elements-asp-mvc-3)

Comment: See the duplicate question above. It should work using `<a href="tel:+123@(num)">...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put `<a href="tel:+351@(num)">@CurrentPage.Telefone</a>` ;)

Answer (score 3):

You might consider checking this Quick Reference:
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

```
@{
    string num = @CurrentPage.Telefone.Replace(" ", "");
}
<a href="tel:+123@(num)">@CurrentPage.Telefone</a>
```

You have to surround the `num` with `()` otherwise the razor engine thinks you are trying to add an email adress or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string num = @CurrentPage.Telefone.Replace(" ", "");
<a href="tel:+123@Html.Raw(num)">@CurrentPage.Telefone</a>
// prints - <a href="tel:+123@num">123 456 789</a>
```

Attempt to use `@Html.Raw(num) instead of @num`